# Selected drop down dynamically using javascript when page reload and will change another dropdown and so on

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i Have table like this

**Menu Table**

```
Id | menu  |
1  | lol   |
2  | lol2  |
```

**Sub Menu table**

```
id | id_menu | sub_menu  |
1  |  1      |  sublol1   |
2  |  1      |  sublol12  |
3  |  2      |  sublol13  |
```

**Sub Sub Menu Table**

```
id  |  id_sub_menu  | sub_sub_menu  |
1   |      1        |   subsublol   |
2   |      2        |   subsublol2  |
```

in other table i combine the table to have relation each other

**Combine table**

```
| idmenu  |  idsubmenu   | idsubsubmenu  |
|  1      |    1         |     1         |
```

I have combo box like this. each of the select option will trigger the option based the previous selected option

Ex :if i select the option in **id="penugasan"** that populate from **Menu**, it will populate new option for **id="jenis_penugasan"** based table **Sub Menu table** and after the option populate, you will chose other option inside **id="jenis_penugasan"** after that it will populate new option for **id="sub_jenis_penugasan"** based table **Sub Sub Menu Table**.

```
  <select id="penugasan" name="penugasan" placeholder="">
       <?php foreach ($menu as $menu) { ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $penugasan->id ?>"><?php echo $penugasan->nama_penugasan; ?></option>
       <?php  } ?>
  </select>

  <select  id="jenis_penugasan" name="jenis_penugasan" ></select>
  <select id="sub_jenis_penugasan" name="sub_jenis_penugasan"></select>
```

**Menu array object from Menu table**

```
Array
(
[menu] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [menu] => lol
             )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [menu] => lol2
            )

    )
```

)

how do i make if the page refresh it will automatically populate 2 other select option **id="jenis_penugasan"** and **id="sub_jenis_penugasan"** based **Combine Table**, i have use ajax but it give me a delay so its didn't populate the **id="sub_jenis_penugasan"**.

Comment: What is the total quantity of choices in all sub and sub sub? I'm just asking, because if the total quantity of all sub and sub sub is not very large, I may have a solution for you, and it doesn't require any ajax.

Comment: about 20 choices,

10 choices for sub and
each sub choices, have 10 choices for sub sub

Comment: I don't know if you noticed, but I created an answer for you. It includes an example, and it should be easy to figure out how to implement so that you no longer need AJAX for autopopulation of your select options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, sorry it took so long, but I wanted to work up an example. FYI I've got a working example on CodePen: https://codepen.io/skunkbad/pen/mMqxRW

So, instead of using AJAX and trying to pull in all the data via HTTP requests which are slow, why not just bring in all the data when you load the page?

My example is dogs, cats, birds, their separate kinds, and names for them. In PHP, I have put these all into arrays:

```
echo json_encode([
    'a' => 'Dogs',
    'b' => 'Cats',
    'c' => 'Birds'
]);

echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';

echo json_encode([
    'a' => [
        'aa' => 'Poodle',
        'ab' => 'Pit Bull',
        'ac' => 'Terrier'
    ],
    'b' => [
        'ba' => 'Maine Coon',
        'bb' => 'Cheshire',
        'bc' => 'Calico'
    ],
    'c' => [
        'ca' => 'Eagle',
        'cb' => 'Hawk',
        'cc' => 'Crow'
    ]
]);

echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';

echo json_encode([
    'aa' => [
        'aaa' => 'Fluffy',
        'aab' => 'Fido',
        'aac' => 'Bert'
    ],
    'ab' => [
        'aba' => 'Doug',
        'abb' => 'Cindy',
        'abc' => 'Randy'
    ],
    'ac' => [
        'aca' => 'Ted',
        'acb' => 'Fred',
        'acc' => 'Leonard'
    ],
    'ba' => [
        'baa' => 'Jasmine',
        'bab' => 'Kendall',
        'bac' => 'Rose'
    ],
    'bb' => [
        'bba' => 'Toby',
        'bbb' => 'Rebecca',
        'bbc' => 'Daniel'
    ],
    'bc' => [
        'bca' => 'Felicity',
        'bcb' => 'Eileen',
        'bcc' => 'James'
    ],
    'ca' => [
        'caa' => 'Mark',
        'cab' => 'Jennifer',
        'cac' => 'George'
    ],
    'cb' => [
        'cba' => 'Jaydon',
        'cbb' => 'Kayla',
        'cbc' => 'Karen'
    ],
    'cc' => [
        'cca' => 'Jamie',
        'ccb' => 'Della',
        'ccc' => 'Mickey'
    ]
]);
```

You end up putting this json encoded data into hidden inputs in your HTML. You end up with HTML like this:

```
<input id="level1" type="hidden" value='{"a":"Dogs","b":"Cats","c":"Birds"}' />
<input id="level2" type="hidden" value='{"a":{"aa":"Poodle","ab":"Pit Bull","ac":"Terrier"},"b":{"ba":"Maine Coon","bb":"Cheshire","bc":"Calico"},"c":{"ca":"Eagle","cb":"Hawk","cc":"Crow"}}' />
<input id="level3" type="hidden" value='{"aa":{"aaa":"Fluffy","aab":"Fido","aac":"Bert"},"ab":{"aba":"Doug","abb":"Cindy","abc":"Randy"},"ac":{"aca":"Ted","acb":"Fred","acc":"Leonard"},"ba":{"baa":"Jasmine","bab":"Kendall","bac":"Rose"},"bb":{"bba":"Toby","bbb":"Rebecca","bbc":"Daniel"},"bc":{"bca":"Felicity","bcb":"Eileen","bcc":"James"},"ca":{"caa":"Mark","cab":"Jennifer","cac":"George"},"cb":{"cba":"Jaydon","cbb":"Kayla","cbc":"Karen"},"cc":{"cca":"Jamie","ccb":"Della","ccc":"Mickey"}}' />

<select id="select1">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
<select id="select2"></select>
<select id="select3"></select>
```

Then, with what is actually some pretty simple javascript, you can autopopulate the dropdowns as you make your selections:

```
var level1 = JSON.parse( $('#level1').val() );
var level2 = JSON.parse( $('#level2').val() );
var level3 = JSON.parse( $('#level3').val() );

$.each(level1, function(k,v){
  $('#select1').append('<option value="' + k + '">' + v + '</option>');
});

$('#select1').on('change', function(){
  $('#select2 option').remove();
  $('#select3 option').remove();
  var selected = $('#select1 option:selected').val();
  if( selected != '' ){
    $('#select2').append('<option value=""></option>');
    $.each(level2[selected], function(k,v){
      $('#select2').append('<option value="' + k + '">' + v + '</option>');
    });
  }
});

$('#select2').on('change', function(){
  $('#select3 option').remove();
  var selected = $('#select2 option:selected').val();
  if( selected != '' ){
    $('#select3').append('<option value=""></option>');
    $.each(level3[selected], function(k,v){
      $('#select3').append('<option value="' + k + '">' + v + '</option>');
    });
  }
});
```

I do this in my own websites, because it is way faster than using AJAX. Hope it helps you.

Now if you want to be able to auto select the dropdowns on page load, I change the javascript to this:

```
var funcs = {
  selectFirst: function( selected ){
    $('#select2 option').remove();
    $('#select3 option').remove();
    if( selected != '' ){
      $('#select2').append('<option value=""></option>');
      $.each(level2[selected], function(k,v){
        $('#select2').append('<option value="' + k + '">' + v + '</option>');
      });
    }
  },
  selectSecond: function( selected ){
    $('#select3 option').remove();
    if( selected != '' ){
      $('#select3').append('<option value=""></option>');
      $.each(level3[selected], function(k,v){
        $('#select3').append('<option value="' + k + '">' + v + '</option>');
      });
    }
  }
};

var level1 = JSON.parse( $('#level1').val() );
var level2 = JSON.parse( $('#level2').val() );
var level3 = JSON.parse( $('#level3').val() );

$.each(level1, function(k,v){
  $('#select1').append('<option value="' + k + '">' + v + '</option>');
});

$('#select1').on('change', function(){
  var selected = $('#select1 option:selected').val();
  funcs.selectFirst( selected );
});

$('#select2').on('change', function(){
  var selected = $('#select2 option:selected').val();
  funcs.selectSecond( selected );
});

// On page load
var initial1 = $('#initial1').val();
var initial2 = $('#initial2').val();
var initial3 = $('#initial3').val();

if( initial1.trim() != '' ){
  funcs.selectFirst( initial1 );
  $('#select1 option[value="' + initial1 + '"]').prop('selected', true);
  if( initial2.trim() != '' ){
    funcs.selectSecond( initial2 );
    $('#select2 option[value="' + initial2 + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    if( initial3.trim() != '' ){
      $('#select3 option[value="' + initial3 + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    }
  }
}
```

And while you are loading up the page, you apply the values through hidden inputs, they will set up the dropdowns the way you want them:

```
<input type="hidden" id="initial1" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value1; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="initial2" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value2; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="initial2" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value3; ?>" />
```

In PHP you just need to assign the values of $value1, $value2, and $value3 from wherever they are coming. So if it's $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, or $_SESSION, that will be determined by your application.

Comment: how do i make if on the page reload it would selected to specific option ? 
i have tried insert  $('#select1').val('a') between Each level function and $('#select1').on('change', function(){. Its selected the "Birds" option, but the  $('#select2') didnt change at all @Brian Gottier

Comment: What will cause the redirect or refresh? Tell me more about what is happening, and your end goal. I'm just asking, because if you're posting form data, or using query string parameters, or cookies, or sessions, or something else, then it would be helpful to know. I can come up with a solution, but without knowing the whole story, I'd probably not be doing exactly what you want.

Comment: okay,so in my "Combine Table" ( look my Question ) have one row data that contain id for eachtable: menu, sub menu and sub sub menu. After that i need to fetch the data from "Combine Table"  to html using ajax with json data just like  you did with your answer before. BUT the problem is when i tried to fetch the row from "combine table" (only one row) the function select onChange did not trigger the drop down sub menu.The idmenu fetch to select1, but when i am trying to fetch id_sub_menu to select2 at the same time, it fetch nothing since the trigger on select2 option didnt work with the parse

Comment: I revised the answer to handle initial values, but I think you are missing the point. There is no longer AJAX needed. The values are all set on page load. You would put the values in the form with PHP, where they can be used without AJAX requests.