# Auto drop down change based from previous selection

Tags: php, jquery, phpmyadmin

I am wanting to change a drop-down selection based on a selection from the previous selection. So I have a database for to store the values which is for a car make and model. The structure is id, make, model
Currently, I have a function to get the make and then get the model and then call the function for the Make selection and then the Model selection but it shows all of them and I do not want that.
So how would I do this?
I have searched around on here and have seen stuff but I am still confused and inexperienced on doing this.

Don't really think you need any of my current code but if you do please let me know.

Comment: You need to use `ajax` and `jquery` or `javascript`. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237900/first-drop-down-menu-to-auto-change-the-options-of-a-second-dropdown)

Comment: Ok, I will take a good at it thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selected drop down dynamically using javascript when page reload and will change another dropdown and so on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45705095/selected-drop-down-dynamically-using-javascript-when-page-reload-and-will-change)

Answer (score 0):

Im not so sure what you mean, but based on my understanding,

You have two dropdown selects,
one as the parent select and the second is the child select, 
the child select dropdown values depends on the parent select,
is that what you meant?

if it is,

a simple way to do this, is to use jquery and ajax,

You have to read basic ajax and event listeners to do this,

1st select dropdown,

```
<select id="parent_select">
</select>

<select id="child_select">
</select>
```

/* This will populate your parent select */

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url that will display all list'
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    success: function(data){
      var output = "";
       $.each(data, function(a,b){
          output += "<option value='"+b.id+"'>"+b.parent_select_name+"  </option>"
        $("#parent_select").append(output);
       });
    }
})
```

/* This will populate your child select upon changing the values of your parent */

```
$(document).on("change", "#parent_select", function(){
  var parent_id = $(this).attr("id");

     $.ajax({
         url: 'url that will display child data where parent_id = parent_id ',
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: { 'parent_id' : parent_id } /* you are passing parent_id*/
         success: function(data){
              $("#child_select").empty();
              var output = "";
              $.each(data, function(a,b){
                  output += "<option id="+b.child_id+">"+b.child_desc+"</option>";
              })
              $("#child_select").append(output);
         }
     })
})
```